# What's the regular expression for positive whole numbers only? (zero is not allowed)

Tags: php, regex, validation

What's the regular expression for positive whole numbers only? (zero is not allowed)

I was able to get the regular expression for numbers only which is  `^\d+$`. I've been trying to look for one online but it's already been an hour so I've decided to post it here on Stack Overflow.

matches:

```
1 || 2 || 444 || 9000 || 012
```

non-matches:

```
9.2 || -90
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're trying to do an arithmetic comparison using regex?  You KNOW you're killing a spider with a shotgun, right?

Comment: No, I'm going to use it for Qty count, I don't want the user to allow 0,-1, 2.3. just positive whole numbers.

Comment: use `parseInt()` or some equivalent..

Comment: @ghoti it seems using Swiss knife to cut a thread.

Comment: randelramirez1, why not just use `if(is_numeric($var) && $var != 0)` ?!

Comment: @ghoti good thought, but `is_numeric` allows negative numbers, decimals, etc.

Comment: Ah, I mis-read.  Then `if(is_numeric($var) && $var > 0)` will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you are looking for `^[1-9]+$` pattern. It'll match `1245`, `2253` etc. But not `1003`. or `0124`. If you want to match the 3rd number (`1003`) as well use `^[1-9]\d*$` pattern.

In php you'd use

```
preg_match('/^[1-9]\d*$/', $subject, $matches)
```

Comment: Thank you also sir, but I'm getting an error.  No ending delimiter '^'  in php. How do I fix it. Thank you again sir.

Comment: You didn't specify its [tag:php]. In php use // as delimeter so pattern will be `/^[1-9]\d*$/`

Answer (score 9):

`^0*[1-9]\d*$` will match all numbers excluding zero.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, the `*?` is intended to be a "[lazy star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification)" , since `*` by itself is greedy. I don't think it's required (or makes any difference) for something as simple as `0*`, but it's valid notation nonetheless.

Comment: It's valid but completely useless and slower because it leads to a lot of unnecessary backtracking.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously:

```
[1-9]\d*
```

(one to nine followed by zero or more digits.)
This would exclude things like 0190, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a regex, but you might consider

```
$opts = array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 1,
        'max_range' => PHP_INT_MAX
    )
);
$n = filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\+?([1-9]|0.)[0-9\.]*$/
```

this pattern may help you, but i think you must your programming language skills  to do arithmetic check. for example in php .  "`$is_positive = $input > 0`" yes it is so easy :)

Comment: thank you sir. yes, I just wanted to use regular expression to validate the user input for before I send the values to the database. Thank again sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[1-9]\d*|[0]*[1-9]\d*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that allows 0 up to 100 but not 01

`^((([0]$)|[1-9][0-9]{0,1})|100)$`