# Regex - to find whole numbers only - problem

Tags: regex, numbers, integer

I am aware that there are quite a few similar threads on this and I've tried the solutions but I can't seem to solve my problems despite reading them - please pardon me.

- [Regex - Find numbers that do not contain two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891821/regex-find-numbers-that-do-not-contain-two-decimal-places)
- [Regex for whole numbers only and not a blank string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223774/regex-for-whole-numbers-only-and-not-a-blank-string)
- [REGEX for whole, positive number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414936/regex-for-whole-positive-number)
- [What's the regular expression for positive whole numbers only? (zero is not allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565937/whats-the-regular-expression-for-positive-whole-numbers-only-zero-is-not-allo)
- [Regex that accepts only numbers (0-9) and NO characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715303/regex-that-accepts-only-numbers-0-9-and-no-characters)
- [Regex to match only numbers in currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071560/regex-to-match-only-numbers-in-currency)

Could any one tell me what's wrong with these two codes below such that it isn't able to fulfil my criteria of selecting only whole numbers. (refer to the two images below)

**Option 1** - how to I prevent $2000.5 from being selected since it isn't a whole number?

```
\$\d+[^.|x](?![0-9])
```

[image]

**Option 2** - This code doesn't select $2000.5 but it isn't selecting $100 (which is a whole number).

```
\$\d+$
```

[image]

**Data**

```
5x Item C $2.5x5, $2.50x1
1 Book $2.55
1x Table $2.59
2x Item A $2000.5x2, 10x Item B $0.5x10
1x Test $2.513, 5x Pear $100x5
$1.430
$1.50 
$1.55
10x Tee $0.5x10
50x SSS $6.5x50
$2.5, $50
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the following pattern:

```
\$\d+(?![0-9.])
```

This matches `$`, followed by a series of one or more digits.  The negative lookahead at the end `(?![0-9.])` ensures that we don't match a number having a decimal component.

### Demo