# Regex - selecting only whole numbers with currency - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: regex

Referring to these posts as reference:

[Regular expression to match numbers with or without commas and decimals in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text)

[Regex - to find whole numbers only - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892703/regex-to-find-whole-numbers-only-problem)

Could any of you enlighten me as to what's wrong with this code below and how do I make it select WHOLE numbers under varying conditions? I added a comma to the negative lookahead to fulfil additional conditions but it is causing some problems for me where I can't get certain numbers selected?

My question - How do I get the whole numbers circled in red to be selected as well? I apologise if the solution may seem obvious but I'm pretty new to this and can't seem to figure the problem with the code below, thanks for your help!

[image: My question - How do I get the whole numbers circled in red to be selected as well?]

```
((INR|CNY|MYR|USD|CHF|EUR|GBP|HKD|MOP|SGD|\$)\d+(\d|,\d{3})*(?![0-9,.]))
```

```
5x Item C $2.5x5, $2.50x1
1 Book $2.55,1x Table $2.59,2x Item A $2000.5x2, 10x Item B $0.5x10
1x Test $2.513, 5x Pear $100x5, $1.430, $1.50, $1.55
10x Tee $0.5x10,2x HKD4,015x2
1x Kettle $50test, 2x Kettle $3.0x, 100x Dogs $5,666,111, 1x Tents $110x1, 5x Pets $500,
10x Shirt $15,000,000x2
15x Pants $3,000x15
100x Paints $1,000,000,000,000x100
$2,000,000,000,000,000
SGD2,000x3
USD2,00
USD2,0
SGD2ttt
CNY5,000, HKD10,000, GBP1,500, EUR1,000x1, GBP1,500
$150,000.0
$1,000,000.55
$1,00.00, $1,0.00
```

Comment: try this `((INR|CNY|MYR|USD|CHF|EUR|GBP|HKD|MOP|SGD|\$)&*([0-9,.]{1,})) `

Comment: Do you want to match `$1,23,456`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?:INR|CNY|MYR|USD|CHF|EUR|GBP|HKD|MOP|SGD|\$)\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*(?:,\d{1,2})?)(?![,.]?\d)/g
```

regex101: https://regex101.com/r/994H89/1

`(?:INR|CNY|MYR|USD|CHF|EUR|GBP|HKD|MOP|SGD|\$)` didn't change from what you have.

`\d{1,3}` allows 1, 2, or 3 digits

`(?:(?:,\d{3})*|\d*(?:,\d{1,2})?)` matches as many groups of three with a comma as possible or any number of digits (possibly 0) followed by possibly a comma and 1 or 2 more digits. To allow any number of digits (not just 3) between commas, change `{3}` to `+`.

`(?!\d|[,.]?\d)` does not let a string end with or be followed by a comma, decimal point, or nothing if it's followed by a digit.

Comment: Hi Skylar, thank you very much for your help. It seems to work as what I wanted it to be. Looks like I need a little more time to digest your code. Thanks again.